# Is the HTTP Library I'm using incompatible with windows 7?

Tags: c#, https, request, xmlhttprequest

I have a class that I am using to create an instance of HTTP Client to perform Get operation on any desired API. Now when I am using it on the machines with Windows 7 it is working smooth in Windows 10, it is giving me the Generic message "An error occurred while sending the request." Am I skipping any step in the process or is it a compatibility/network issue?

Here's my code of the class

```
   public static class HttpService
    {

        private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        static HttpService()
        {
            
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        }
        public static async Task<string> ExecuteGetStringAsync(string endpoint)
        {
            string res = string.Empty;
            
           
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(endpoint);
            
            // Handle the response
            switch (response.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                    res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
                    break;
                case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                    await _logger.Error($"StatusCode: {HttpStatusCode.NotFound}, Response: {res}");
                    throw new HttpException(404, "Not Found");
                case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                    res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    await _logger.Error($"StatusCode: {HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError}, Response: {res}");
                    throw new HttpException(501, $"ExecuteGet->Failed: {res}");
                case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                    await _logger.Error($"StatusCode: {HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized}, Response: {res}");
                    throw new HttpException(401, "Unauthorized access");
                default:
                    int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                    await _logger.Error($"StatusCode: {statusCode}, Response: {res}");
                    throw new HttpException(statusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);

            }
            
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using that method to connect the server using API which I'm building using serverIp

```
private static async Task ConnectToServer(string serverIp)
        {
            string releaseUrl = string.Format("https://{0}/bin/APILinks?cmd=connectToServer", serverIp);
            try
            {
                await HttpService.ExecuteGetStringAsync(releaseUrl);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await _logger.Error($", serverIp: {serverIp}, cookie: {cookie}, error: {ex.Message}, stacktrace: {ex.StackTrace}");
            }
        }
```

Adding the error & Stack Trace That I got in the log:

```
error: An error occurred while sending the request., 

stacktrace:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at MyApplication.Common.HttpService.<ExecuteGetStringAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at MyApplication.Common.Service.<ConnectToServer>d__38.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at MyApplication.Common.Service.<ConnectToServer>d__34.MoveNext()
```

Comment: It is not usually the library unless is has to do with the version of TLS. Normally it is a defautl http header that is different.  Often it is the user agent which is the user default browser.  See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: so you mean to say adding 

_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36");

to my constructor might fix it?

Comment: yes.  As I said, some servers refuse a connection and only allow certain browsers.  The way server determine the browser is the useragent.  In c# you can specify which browser you are trying to clone by setting the useragent.

Comment: Tried that but still getting same error log.

Comment: It is looking like a TLS issue.  The default TLS is probably different on Win 7 and Win 10.  Best way of debugging is use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare working and non working results.  TLS is used for authentication with HTTPS.  The TLS is sent before the request is sent.  When TLS fails there is no request.  So check sniffer to see if there is a request.  If you get a request then check the status in the response which is normally 200 OK or a 400/500 error.  If no request than check the version of TLS.  Should be 1.2 or 1.3.  Probably Win 7 uses 1.2 and Win10 uses 1.3.